# Some labels disappear depending on zoom (scale dependent vis is turned off)

Tags: qgis, labeling

for one layer I have an issue with a very few select labels disappearing depending on zoom level. See label "3" on the right in below screenshots. 
"Scale dependency" is inactive and "Show all labels" is active. This only happens with a few labels in this layer - and always the same. I have another layer that is very similar but based on a different variable and there all labels reliably get rendered.

I found that some labels keep appearing/disappearing just by panning the map around in the same zoom level. I've played around with the various placement options and found that 'placing in whole centroid' vs 'placing in visible centroid' leads to those faulty labels not appearing at all in any zoom or panning state.

Is there a fault with the polygons/centroids?

In another layer using the same map/polygons this problem does not occur.

[image: Zoomed in with visible label "3"]
[image: Zoomed out with label "3" not visible]
[image: Label settings with scale dependency inactivated and show all labels active]

Comment: I have to correct my last statement: I have now found the same problem in another layer using the same country polygons. While the labels disappear over different countries it is the same strange behaviour. 
The map is a Natural Earth 10m map.

Comment: Perhaps there's something strange about the geometry of those polygons. Check for invalid geometry. Check for an unexpectedly large feature extent by selecting one of them and "zoom to selection". Look for tiny outlier parts. Copy the feature into a new layer, and see if you can correct the geometry.

Comment: The island of Guadeloupe looks like it might have an invalid "hourglass" shape. Check and make sure its geometry is valid.

Comment: Thanks, Csk. I checked geometry and it looks alright. No overlaps, no invalid hourglass shapes. I've got the same problem with Indonesia and South Africa where the lables just won't appear at all. I think for this task i may just have to do without the lables for now - but i'd still be keen to find out the reason for this odd label behaviour.